# Can someone explain the homepage new look?

Tags: discussion, design, new-users

Can someone explain the *new* look of the Tex.StackExchange homepage and what is displayed? I could find no reference to the changes and did not know who to ask.  I think I get the *Here's how it works* section, but I don't understand the rest of the page. Previously, when a user signed onto the homepage you saw the latest questions that were asked, all on one page.

**Screenshot added**

[image]

Now, it seems the latest or newest questions are accessed with two button clicks (Questions, then **newest**) showing the newest 40,000+ questions via 2707 tabs (at 15 question per page). The displayed questions seem, to this user, randomly selected -- although I assumed there is some logic or reason behind the selection.

This may not be the typical TeX/LaTeX questions and perhaps the question is asked in the wrong place, but the answer will help me to navigate and enjoy the site again.

Comment: a pleasing alternative might be to replace the existing list of questions with the original one page of recent questions.

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure if I follow you. Could you please make a screenshot of the "wrong" homepage so that we know what's going on? If I remember correctly, you should be able to edit the post, upload the image and add a link to it there.

Comment: I think, The new homepage was designed (`status-by-design`)to attract new people to answer/read hot questions on TeX.SX and to make new users get acquainted with `Here's how it works` section on `.SE` websites . `with two button clicks`(Questions, then newest)  one will be redirected to the right active (earlier) page where [questions feed is seen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NxTWI.png). Once registered and logged into TeX.SX one can see the `active` Q page feed

Comment: I have to concur with the original questioner.  The previous web page displayed a compact list of the titles only of all recent activity (Posts, Answers, and edits)  This made it very easy to quickly check for items of interest.  I also would like to be able to display that original layout (either with or without login would be fine).  I think the new format is very nice for a new user but it is not as convenient or as quick to use.

Comment: See [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595): "2013-04-02: Users are now shown a persistent (but dismissable) banner linking to /about on the site."

Answer (score 24):

What you are looking at is the new homepage for *anonymous* visitors. Folks who have accounts and are signed in still see the same questions list we've always shown that is sorted in reverse chronological order by latest activity and don't see the "here's how it works banner".

This new anonymous homepage attempts to pick questions that are more likely to show off what the site is about. It is similar to the [monthly hot questions list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/?tab=month). The "here's how it works" banner introduced a new visitor to how Stack Exchange and the TeX site work, and the tags above the questions are intended to both introduce new visitors to the tag system and to encourage them to browse the site and see what else may catch their eye.

The list of recently modified questions is still available for everyone via the [active questions list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active).